# Text value for Schema.org "price" property?

Tags: schema.org, price

I'm working on a piece of structured data, in JSON-LD format (should it matter).

While looking through the [`price` property page](https://schema.org/price) of Schema.org, I saw that you can also add text as price value. However, it doesn't seem to be documented anywhere what texts are allowed.

Does anyone know what texts are allowed?

I've tried to fill in random texts while using the [Structured Data Testing Tool](https://search.google.com/structured-data/testing-tool), but that gave an error that it didn't get recognised.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Schema.org doesn’t restrict (nor document/recommend) what kind of [`Text`](http://schema.org/Text) value the `price` property can have.

Most prices will have a [`Number`](http://schema.org/Number) value, and unless you have a good reason not to use it, you should go with `Number`, too, following their "Usage guidelines".

I guess possible reasons for expecting `Text` could be:

- CMS that don’t (easily) allow to output the price separately from the currency symbol. Having "5 EUR" as `price` is better than not providing a `price` at all.
- Authors that want to say "gratis" or "free" instead of "0".

Comment: Thank you for the answer (and edit of the question). In this specific case the price will be set in the physical store, hence no price is given. However, when I fill a text value in as price, it gives an error that the value is not a valid price specification when trying it in the [Structured Data Testing Tool](https://search.google.com/structured-data/testing-tool). Hence the question. I used the first example of [this page](https://schema.org/Product) and edited the price.

Comment: @SanderKoedood: Google’s SDTT is not a Schema.org validator; Google has its own rules what it expects from Schema.org markup for getting their rich result features. So while providing a text value is fine according to Schema.org, Google may decide to parse only numbers. --- If you don’t have prices, you should omit the `price` property (yes, this means that Google won’t show a Product Rich Snippet, but a price to show is required for this snippet, so it won’t work without prices).